# What is the difference between manager.Pool and Pool in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Say I want to share a dictionary between processes. If I have defined a manager, what is the difference between instantiating a pool using `manager.Pool()` and `multiprocessing.Pool()`?

Ex: What is the difference between the two `with` statements in `main_1` and `main_2`?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from random import random


def func(d):
    pid = mp.current_process().pid
    time.sleep(3 * random())
    d[pid] = 'I added this'


def main_1():
    print('Start of main 1')
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with manager.Pool() as pool:  # using manager
            pool.map(func, [d] * 4)

        print(d)


def main_2():
    print('Start of main 2')
    manager = mp.Manager()
    try:
        d = manager.dict()
        with mp.Pool() as pool:  # using multiprocessing
            pool.map(func, [d] * 4)

        print(d)
    finally:
        manager.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_1()
    main_2()
```

#### More generally

Are all processes started after a Manager exists in the scope automatically served by it?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool): "context can be used to specify the context used for starting the worker processes. Usually a pool is created using the function `multiprocessing.Pool()` or the `Pool()` method of a context object. In both cases context is set appropriately" 
So, that should just be the same

Comment: I know it's a MRP, but I cant help but pointing to the nice [how to ensure the dictionary in python is threadsafe](https://superfastpython.com/thread-safe-dictionary-in-python/) blog post, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `manager.Pool` and `multiprocessing.Pool` in Python are used for creating a pool of worker processes to execute tasks in parallel. However, there are some differences between them.

`multiprocessing.Pool` is a built-in class provided by the Python multiprocessing module. It creates a pool of worker processes, where each process executes tasks independently. The tasks can be submitted to the pool as functions or methods to be executed in parallel.

On the other hand, `manager.Pool` is a class provided by the Python `multiprocessing.managers` module. It also creates a pool of worker processes like `multiprocessing.Pool`. However, `manager.Pool` is used for creating a pool of processes that can be shared among multiple Python processes. This means that the processes in the pool can be accessed and used by multiple Python processes, making it a good choice for distributed computing.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this. What does it mean that the processes themselves are accessible from other Python processes? And is there a difference between the two `Pool`s w.r.t. the using/mutating the shared dictionary?

Comment: @Stalpotaten consider your example using the `Manager.Pool`. Within the context manager, you can do stuff like put that pool in a queue and pass it to another Process as an argument. That is, doing `p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=some_func, args=(pool,)); p1.start()` will not raise error, and neither will `q = multiprocessing.Queue(); q.put(pool)`. This means, the pool you have is picklable and can be shared across processes (because you have access only to proxy of that pool through the manager, not the actual pool). But doing all this with `multiprocessing.Pool` will result in an error

Comment: @Stalpotaten this part of the documentation should add some more helpful context if you haven't already seen it https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers